# Export VS formatting settings to MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, monodevelop

I am working in a small team of developers (myself and one other), and we are working on different platforms (myself on Windows, him on Linux); this is intentional so that we can be sure that all features are completely cross-platform compatible. This means that he is working with MonoDevelop 5.9, and myself with Visual Studio Community 2013.

Since our code formatting options are slightly different, can I export my VS code formatting options for him to use in MonoDevelop? We have decided to use Unix line endings, and VS supports that so it's not an issue, but we always seem to have slightly different indentation, spacing, and bracketing settings.

Comment: Ensure too that everyone has set the IDE to _keep tabs_ rather than _insert spaces_.  Inserting spaces renders the file at whatever tab-stop that user has set for **everyone**.  Keeping tabs will have that file display differently based on user preference

Comment: @MickyDuncan we have decided on a consistant spacing (4 spaces == a tab), so we are using the *insert spaces* option as well. I personally think that spaces make the code look better outside of the IDE (aka on Github, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MonoDevelop / Xamarin Studio has a matching C# Text Policy that can be applied to match the Visual Studio code style defaults.

In MD/XS, open up *Preferences / Source Code / Code Formatting / C# source code*

In that panel, you can select from the various built-in default styles, including 'Microsoft Visual Studio'. After selecting it, you can customize it if needed to match any changes that you might have made in VS.

If you need to reformat any source files after that selection is made, MD/XS has a menu command for reformatting to that style: *Edit / Format / Format Document*

The styles are stored in an XML-based file (*XamarinStudio-5.0 / Policies / Default.mdpolicy.xml*) but personally I do not know of this file format matching any Visual Studio file:

```
<TextStylePolicy inheritsSet="VisualStudio" inheritsScope="text/plain" scope="text/x-csharp">
</TextStylePolicy>
```